# How to handle back button in other application?

Tags: android, back-button, back-button-control

I have navigated to maps application from myapplication using following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

1. when i press back button in maps it navigates to my application.
2. When i minimize maps application and open maps from recently open list apps and press back button, My application is not opening.

Could any help me on this ?

Do i need to add any flags to intent to open my application in second case ? or any idea please suggest me..

Comment: This is correct behavior. If you are minimizing the maps app, then re-opening it, your app is no longer the logical "back" from there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you should set [android:alwaysRetainTaskState](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always) **true** in your root activity.